# Failed to apply efforts to joints in gazebo on ros fuerte

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I follow this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API) using Fuerte, but the link does not rotate after

$rosservice call gazebo/apply_joint_effort '{joint_name: link_joint, effort: 0.01, start_time: 10000000000, duration: 1000000000}'

instead I get

ERROR: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details

I have launched

$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch

on ROS Fuerte, Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

Where could I see sender's logs as suggested by the error msgs above?

Is there another way (how) to apply effort to joints in gazebo in Fuerte?

I note that the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API) I follow was written for C-Turtle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33461/failed-to-apply-efforts-to-joints-in-gazebo-on-ros-fuerte/) by [natekoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/2334/natekoenig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The basic problem is that there was a bug in my electric-fuerte migration, fixed in the following patch, to be released with 1.6.8.
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/changeset/39394

---

Originally posted by [natekoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/2334/natekoenig/) with karma: 56 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1